# Add <br> tag in asp.net gridview column data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on gridview and I am binding the data from code behind

Dim dataTblRep As New DataTable
Dim dataRowRep As DataRowdataRowRep = dataTblRep.NewRow

```
dataRowRep("Batch Number") = "Totals : "
dataRowRep("Batch details") = "A" & <br/> & "B"

dataRowRep("Completed Docs") = TotEntryCount
dataRowRep("Received Docs") = TotSrcCount
dataTblRep.Rows.Add(dataRowRep)

gvRepOutput.DataSource = dataTblRep
gvRepOutput.DataBind()
```

So, in Batch details I am adding the two values from datatable and I want the "A" and "B" on seperate lines within the cell.  But in the output I am getting "`A <br/> B`"

I have tried HtmlDecode but it is not working.  Also, I am not using any Template Fields and I have the gridviews AutoGenerateColumns option set to True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Template column as BoundColumns HtmlEncode by default.

Comment: Thomas, I was hoping to avoid that.  The code above is not my exact example.  I am dynamically building the columns and the number of columns may vary.  But, based on this, I may have to dynamically add templated columns to the grid view.

Comment: I turned auto generating off and dynamically added bound fields to the grid view based on the number of columns and set each bound fields htmlencode property to false and that did the trick for me.  Thanks, Thomas!